# group by clause and mongo db output format

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

We are using below query:-

```
    db.action.aggregate([ 
{ $match: {"$and": [{"eventId":{"$in": ["LAS20"]}},{"id":
   { "$in": db.logins.distinct("id",{"$and": [{"agentRole": 
       {"$in": ["tv_AFC","DV_HP","DV_TECH"]}},{"loginLogoutTime":
           {"$gte": ISODate("2021-04-20T00:00:00.000-0500"),
               "$lt": ISODate("2021-04-27T23:59:00.000-0500")}} ]}) }
    },{"timeStamp": {"$gte": ISODate("2021-04-20T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": 
        ISODate("2021-04-27T23:59:00.000-0400")}}]}}, 
{ $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timeStamp" }}, User: "$id" ,
Region:"$Region"},
JOBCOUNT: {$addToSet: "$jobId"}}}, 
{ $project: {  "_id" : NumberInt(0), "Region": "$_id.Region" , "Dates" : "$_id.Dates","TotalJOB" : 
    {$size:"$JOBCOUNT"}} }
])
```

**currently getting output: below**

```
   Region   Dates        TotalJOB
   nw         2021-04-27     2
```

but we need output REGION COUNTS PER DAY. Group by REGION and timestamp , instead of group by id need to group by region.

```
REGION   Trunc(Timestamp)   count(*)

pw           05th-feb-21         1165

nw           05th-feb-21          2165
```

thanks,

we have document like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6076719fd1d4bc00124041"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "eventId" : "LAS20",
    "eventName" : "",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2021-04-14T04:37:51.085Z"),
    "eventMethod" : "AI response",
    "resourceName" : "",
    "targetType" : "",
    "resourseUrl" : "",
    "operationName" : "getLastReleaseNumber",
    "functionStatus" : "SUCCESS",
    "results" : "{\"flowStatus\":\"SUCCESS\",\"flowStatusMessage\":\"\",\"lastReleaseNumber\":\"0.1.175\",\"lasUpgradeType\":\"F\"}",
    "pageId" : "",
    "ban" : "",
    "jobId" : "",
    "wrid" : "",
    "jobType" : "",
    "id" : "bt9976",
    "Region" : "NW",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

expected output should be like:-

```
REGION   Trunc(Timestamp)   count(*)
    
    pw           05th-feb-21         1165
    
    nw           05th-feb-21          2165
```

Yes added the condition:-
Output is showing below:-

{
"Dates" : "2021-04-17",
"TotalJOB" : 6485
}

/* 40 */
{
"Dates" : "2021-04-18",
"TotalJOB" : 2618
}

but we need outputlike below:-

```
REGION   Trunc(Timestamp)   count(*)
        
        pw           05th-feb-21         1165
        
        nw           05th-feb-21          2165
```

Comment: post some example document in your question.

Comment: Thanks turivishal, posted the sample document.

Comment: what is the issue in this [query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/84SujBUh2MN)? and also there is no Region field in your example document.

Comment: we need the output in format: REGION COUNTS PER DAY. Group by REGION and timestamp , instead of group by id need to group by region.

Comment: output should like: REGION   Trunc(Timestamp)   count(*)

pw           05th-feb-21         1165

nw           05th-feb-21          2165

Comment: please check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1WtKCATRkdV).

Comment: Thanks Turivishal, for ex, if we have to select for particular dates , how can we put in the query.

Comment: just add $match stage in first stage and match your date condition.

Comment: thanks turvishal, yes added the condition getting this o/p: -{ "Dates" : "2021-04-17", "TotalJOB" : 6485 }

/* 40 */ { "Dates" : "2021-04-18", "TotalJOB" : 2618 }

Comment: But we need the o/p in format: REGION   Trunc(Timestamp)   count(*)
        
        pw           05th-feb-21         1165
        
        nw           05th-feb-21          2165   kindly suggest.

Comment: your question is not clear, please add your sample documents and expected result from that result, only in json format. not in tabular format.